# MFC dialog title is getting trimmed after including class name

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

We are trying to add the class name for a MFC dialog by adding the class option as below in the .rc file just after the CAPTION option
**CLASS "TestClass"**

and then the below code is added in the InitInstance method of CWinAPP.

```
WNDCLASS wndClass;
::GetClassInfo(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), _T("#32770"), &wndClass);
wndClass.lpszClassName = _T("TestClass");
AfxRegisterClass(&wndClass);
```

With the above code the class name is set on the dialog but the caption is getting trimmed to one character. Without the class name changes, the caption is displayed correctly.

Can anyone please tell what might be causing the dialog caption to be trimmed.

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you're seeing?  Also, what is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: If some GDI text is showing as one character, maybe it's that unicode and ANSI are getting mixed up, a _T prefix is misssing

Comment: I am trying to add class name for an existing dialog so that other application can find this dialog using class name. The dialog was displaying properly before this. After adding class name the dialog title is trimmed. For example if the dialog title is "Test" then it’s getting trimmed to 't' when the dialog is displayed.

Comment: Then it's not what I said earlier. I can't reproduce this error. Your code works for a simple dialog. Please show minimum verifiable example where it fails.

Comment: Even i tried with a simple dialog, it works fine. But when i launch this dialog from our framework this error is seen. So i think the issue is with our framework. But i am not able to find what property/setting in the framework is causing the dialog title to be trimmed.

Comment: What is the EXACTLY the expected text? And what is EXACTLY the text you see? May be this is a limitation of the maximum text size support!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani You were right in guessing UNICODE and ANSI mix up. In our framework, the default MFC dialog class name is already registered using the ANSI version of the API(RegisterClassExA). So on changing my dialog code to ANSI version of windows API it worked fine.